# LibGDX set bullet initial position around the ship's circle 2D graphics

Tags: java, libgdx

Have a small issue with some thoughts, but have no idea which libraries to use and how.
So far I am creating 2D game and I have a small ship sprite and bullets. 
For this moment my bullets launched from the central point of the ship.

What I want:

- To create something like a circle around my ship and make possible to
  fire bullets from the circle lines according to the direction. Maybe
  it is possible to make by using Quaternion class, but need some
  hints, how to start.
- Another idea, is to create another bullet, which
  will be always parallel to the first one and will be fired
  simultaneously.

Image below describes what I is my aim in this project.
[image]

So far my update() method inside player class makes next operations:

```
    @Override
public void update() {
//When player touches the screen, TouchInputHandler class sets the variable isAiming = true.
    if (TouchInputHandler.isAiming) {
//Creating an Vector2 object which takes coordinates from user input on the screen.
        Vector2 aim = new Vector2(TouchInputHandler.getAimDirection().x, TouchInputHandler.getAimDirection().y);

//Checking if aim is real value. 
//Waiting for the delay between previous and next bullet launched.
        if (aim.len2() > 0 && cooldownRemaining <= 0) {

//cooldownFrames if final static value equal to 6. 
//So loop will go through 6 times before next bullet.
            cooldownRemaining = cooldownFrames;
//Taking the current position of the ship and applying it to the current position of bullet.
            Vector2 currentPos = new Vector2(position.x, position.y);
//Substituting current bullet position from the aim position and getting direction vector.
            aim.sub(currentPos);
 //Normalizing the aim (bullet direction) vector, so the sum of scalars of vector = 1;
        aim.nor();

          //Incresing the speed of bullet movement.
            aim.x *= 10;
            aim.y *= 10;

           //adding new entity with the bullet currentPos and direction where it has to move.
            EntityManager.addEntity(new Bullet(currentPos, aim));

//After bullet has been launched, set isAiming to false.
                  TouchInputHandler.isAiming = false;
              }
    }

//decreasing cooldown Remaining in every loop until it will be equal 0 and bullet'll be ready again.
    if (cooldownRemaining > 0)
        cooldownRemaining--;
//method that is responsible for player movement.
    motionMove();

}
```

If you need any other parts of code, or another information, just ask.
I will very appreciate your help or any hints. Thank you!

Comment: So you want, that the bullet start from the circle, instaed of the center point?
You don't need quaternion, as you are in 2D space. A quaternion is a direction vector, with a rotation applied to it (a roll around this vector). I think a 2D Vecotr would do it in your case, but tell me what exactly do you want to achieve and if my assumption is right.

Comment: Ohh, thank for your respond. Yes, your assumption is right. I want to make bullets fired from the borders of the circle, but not from the central point of the ship. Any ideas, how to implement this circle? Because for now bullets comes out from inside of the ship and this looks ugly. Or there can be any other way to implement this feature? Thank you!

Comment: You have to use a `Vector2 direction`, which is a normalized vector, giving the percent of movement in x and percent of movement in y direction. The you have to calculate the movement in both directions.

Comment: I think you are explaining now something which I've already done. Please look at my code. As I explained, my normalised vector of direction works perfectly. 
The thing I need is to make possible to set initial position of bullet not from the middle of the ship.

Comment: You don't need more. Just add the x and y value to the position.x and y, respecting the direction.x and direction.y as well as your size/radius

Comment: Try `startPos.set(position).add(direction.scl(radius))`. Don't forget to normalize the direction after that, as scl applies the scaling to the Vector, not only to the returned. This should be enought for your needs.

Comment: Ohh, thank you, this is exactly that I wanted! Sorry for misunderstanding. Now this is clear for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `direction` vector you have to get the starting position.
To do this you only need to scale the `direction` vector with the `radius` of your circle and add this vector to the circles center:

```
bulletStart.set(position).add(direction.scl(radius));
```

`position` is the center of your ship.
`direction` is the normalized direction vector.
`radius` is the circles radius.

Note, that the methods of `Vector2` change the `Vector` and return him for chaining. So after calling `direction.scl(radius)` the `direction` is not normalized anymore.

Another note: This is not really accurate (as much as i understood), as the length of the `Vector` is `vector.x + vector.y` instead of `sqrt(vector.x² + vector.y²)`, which would be the radius. But the difference should not be to big in your case and i just can't think about the right formula at the moment, even if it should not be that hard. If someone knows it, tell me please :P